# axios get to constantly update

Tags: reactjs, axios, postman, get-request

I have a code in reactjs with which I'm using axios the get some data. It all is running well, but when I use postman to send more data to display, the new data is rendering dynamically, I have to refresh the page to show it
How can correct this?

Comment: Need more info.

Comment: Please show your code so we can help you!